# Converting 2TB of gziped multiline JSONs to NDJSONs

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-beam

For my research I have a dataset of about 20,000 gziped multiline json files (~2TB, all have the same schema). I need to process and clean this data (I should say I'm very new to data analytics tools).

After spending a few days reading about Spark and Apache Beam I'm convinced that the first step would be to first convert this dataset to NDJSONs. In most books and tutorials they always assume you are working with some new line delimited file.

What is the best way to go about converting this data? 
I've tried to just launch a large instance on gcloud and just use gunzip and jq to do this. Not surprisingly, it seems that this will take a long time.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Beam supports unzipping file if you use [TextIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.14.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.html).
But the delimiter remains to be New Line.

For multiline json you can read complete file using in parallel and then convert the json string to pojo and eventually reshuffle the data to utilize parallelism.

So the steps would be

```
Get the file list > Read individual files > Parse file content to json objects > Reshuffle > ...
```

You can get the file list by [FileSystems.match("gcs://my_bucker").metadata()](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.14.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileSystems.html#match-java.util.List-).

Read individual files by Compression `Compression.detect((fileResouceId).getFilename()).readDecompressed(FileSystems.open(fileResouceId))`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I do have a couple of questions:
1) In the end this will be all one pipeline? 2)  For reading the compressed file I was trying `beam.Create(json.loads(filesystems.FileSystems.open('./multiline.json.gz').read()))` but was running into some issues. What is the Compression library you are using in `Compression.detect((fileResouceId).getFilename()).readDecompressed(FileSystems.open(fileResouceId))`? 

Again, thanks for the help and patience :)

Answer (score 0):

Converting to NDJSON is not necessary if you use [`sc.wholeTextFiles`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#wholeTextFiles-java.lang.String-int-). Point this method at a directory, and you'll get back an `RDD[(String, String)]` where `._1` is the filename and `._2` is the content of the file.

Comment: I was attempting to do this with Apache Beam and run it on Google Dataflow (the university has google cloud credits). Do you believe Spark is better suited for this task? (again, apologies for my ignorance here, this is my first project with this type of tools).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unfamiliar with Apache Beam, so I couldn't advise on which tool to use. I can say, however, that Apache Spark is certainly capable of doing what you need, including automatically parsing the JSON and doing analytics after you've gotten the data loaded.

Comment: You can also perform this with DataFlow. Apache Beam is an agnostic framework that just by changing the Runner you can use your code in multiple backends. Dataflow is able to autoscale without any effort from your side, but it has a cost (not cheap at all). So I do agree that NDJSON is not needed and certainly if you are using apache beam you can use `FileIO` transform and, if needed, create your own functions and transforms to process your data

Comment: Thanks for the help @TravisHegner and @JuanUrrego
Alright I will keep pushing at it. I'm at the moment struggling to write a `JsonFileSource` that can uncompressed the file, parse the JSON and then emit each object in the top level array. My `JsonFileSource` is looking pretty similar to  this: [](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/data-science-preprocessing)


Btw, what tool would you guys have used if you had to do something like this?